# Defender cost in text field is not displaying

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a game of Glitch garden. In this game, we have defenders that prevent attackers to enter into our area. The game is almost completed. The game has the functionality of lives defenders have, star cost.
I have also added functionality that when we play the game, it should also display defender cost value each defender has. So I added a text field as child, in defender parent. The order of the layer is correct. There is no error in scripting also. Not even showing any error in console. But when I play game, it is not showing the cost of defenders. Cost is initialized in defenders script which is attached on every defender
All script is properly linked. Can any help me to sort out the issue?
[image]

Comment: It is related to your parent gameObject's position. Double click on your text and see where it is placed. Also you can attach the text component to your parent and move the parent to the game view. Another important thing you should know about text component is, always set horizontal and vertical overflows as ```overflow``` and then scale up/down your text gameObject. So that you can add as many characters you want, the text component will always be expanded.

Comment: I checked the position of the child with respect to the parent Gameobejct. and set the child's position accordingly.also set horizontal and vertical overflow as overflow.but still not showing the cost of defenders

Comment: Is it visible in Editor mode? And the problem you are facing is in game mode?

Comment: It is showing me the default value, the value of the text field. It should take this value dynamically from the defender prefab and shows the cost of each defender.

Comment: Since you are using prefabs, you might want to check it here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1426825/how-can-i-apply-a-text-variable-to-a-prefab.html

Comment: Have done this in defenderbutton prefab.I added given below lines in LabelButtonwithCost(). Text costText = GetComponentInChildren<Text>();                                                            costText.text = defenderPrefab.GetStarCost().ToString();                                                 script is correct and order of layer in editor is also correct.it should show dynamic value any how.couldn't understand why is it not showing value dynmically

Comment: Can you add console.log to your cost variable in the script and see in the console if it is reading properly. If it is showing properly then I am sure that the text prefab that is getting called in the script is not from the active text gameobject in the hierarchy window. Check it again, you will find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your text value is more than RectTransform size. (I saw you use 64 as High and use 84 as Width when value more than 2 digit it will exceed and not appear)
try to reduce **Font Size** and watch result.

Ps. I need more information about your code while you instantiate button (if you do) and setup value for render.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is sorted out.

I have written start function spell wrong. As c£ is case sensitive, I wrote star' instead of Start.
Now defender's cost is updated dynamically.
Thank you all